# AWS Amplify Console shows weird xml instead of 404

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, web-services, http-status-code-404, aws-amplify

I´ve deployed a vanilla js app via the AWS amplify console and got a subdomain from amplifyapp.com. When I call source files directly, f.e. `master.myappid.amplifyapp.com/js/index.js`, the content is being shown like it should. Also, when calling the domain without any specific file, it will show the `index.html` as expected. But, when calling non-existant folders or just a sub-folder, not a specific file in it, it will not throw a 404, but instead show a weird xml response, something like this:

```
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>X</RequestId><HostId>X</HostId></Error>
```

Also, when calling non-existant files, f.e. `/abc.html`, it will also show this message. How can I setup a rule to make AWS Amplify Console show a 404 when sub-directories with no index.html, non-existant directorys or non-existant files are being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was way easier than expected. Just add a rewrite rule (In your amplify console at the left sidebar) with a source address of `<*>`, a target address of `/404.html` (or any other error page) and a type of "404 (Not found)". Any 404´s will now be redirected to 404.html, which you will have to create and write some informative 404 page for ;)

Comment: I believe this solution will mean the page still returns a '200' status code where it should be returning a 404 which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 2):

The AWS Amplify documentation has further detail on [using Redirects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html) to handle this situation. For my case, I created a SPA app (React) and you must [set up a Redirect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa) for direct URL navigation to work with Amplify.

Comment: You saved my day. I am really amazed that why AWS doesn't include this configuration in app init wizard or enlist such requirements conspicuously somewhere.